# incompatible types when assigning to type struct

Tags: c

I'm writing a simple game and I've recently encountered problem that doesn't seem difficult to solve, however I'm out of ideas.

in file blocks.c among other functions I've defined a simple function:

```
field block_get_field_coordinates(int x, int y)
{
    field temp;

    temp.x = floor( x / 65 ) * 65 + 15;
    temp.y = floor( y / 65) * 65 + 15;
    return temp;
}
```

field is a struct declared in file grid.h

```
struct field
{
    int x, y;
}f;

typedef struct field field;
```

And in main.c when I tried the following:

```
f = block_get_field_coordinates(blocks[x][y].x4, blocks[x][x].y4);
```

Where f is 'field' I got an error:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct field' from type 'int'
```

I really don't know what I've done wrong here. Other functions from blocks.c work without throwing out any errors.

Interestingly, when I copied just the declaration of struct field, function block_get_field_coordinates into separate file, it worked.

Comment: you are missing a `,` in the function call.

Comment: Does the compiler see a **declaration** of your function? If it doesn't, it will assume `int` for the return type.

Comment: In main.c I included line #include"blocks.h" because I read that including not header files isn't advisable. Other functions from blocks.c are of type void so that's probably why I haven't had this problem already. What should be done here?

Comment: Where did you read that including header files isn't advisable? burn that reference.

Comment: I mean files that are NOT headers such as blocks.c in that case.
I didn't include headers of funcions from blocks.c in blocks.h and that's why I got an error. But that happened only with that one function, others worked fine (probably because they were of type void?).

Answer (score 4):

You need your main to see a declaration of the function.

e.g. in main

```
extern field block_get_field_coordinates(int x, int y);
```

or better yet put it in block.h as main is going to need the type as well as any functions that use the type.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!
How is that possible that other functions worked without knowing the type returned by the functions? I wanted to add the headers of funcions to blocks.h at the end of writing the code as everything seemed to work just fine.

Comment: By default C assumes everything returns an int. Does that explain why some stuff worked?